# The repository 'http://repository.spotify.com xenial Release' does not have a Release file

Tags: linux, ubuntu, spotify, apt

On Ubuntu 16.04, I've installed the spotify  repository according to their install instructions:

The [spotify installation instructions](https://www.spotify.com/ca-en/download/linux/) are:

> 1. Add the Spotify repository signing key to be able to verify downloaded packages 
>      `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver
>      hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys
>      BBEBDCB318AD50EC6865090613B00F1FD2C19886`
> 2. Add the Spotify repository `echo deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list`
> 3. Update list of available packages `sudo apt-get update`
> 4. Install Spotify `sudo apt-get install spotify-client`

But when I run Step 3 I get this error:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
...
Reading package lists... Done   
E: The repository 'http://repository.spotify.com xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
```

Here's the repository:

```
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list 
deb http://repository.spotify.com xenial stable non-free
```

How do I fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This post should really be on https://askubuntu.com/ or https://community.spotify.com, not http://stackoverflow.com

To answer your question anyway. You did not follow step 2 properly. Remove xenial between http://repository.spotify.com and stable.